# How to style li's using value of clicked li?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am a bit stuck here and would appreciate being put on the right path.
Basically I have a list of li's with color names, and once one of the boxes is clicked I need all the li's to change background colors to the clicked color, and also have the clicked li become bold and uppercase.

How can I get the value of the clicked li and apply it to the siblings? (Have to use jquery/javascript, can't modify the html)

Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Project 18</title>
  <style>
    html {margin:2em; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
    h1 {margin:0;}
    h2 {color:#369;}
    hr {margin:2em 0;}
    .color-list {margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
      .color-list li {margin:0.5em 0; padding:0.5em; color:#fff; border:1px solid #000; background-color:#000;}
      .color-list li:hover {cursor:pointer;}
    nav ul {margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
      nav li {display:inline-block;}
      nav li a {display:block; padding:1em; color:#ccc; text-decoration:none; background-color:gray;}
      .tabs-sections {padding:0 1em; border:1px solid gray;}
      .active a {color:#000; background-color:lightgray;}
      .s2, .s3 {display:none;}
  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header><h1>Project 18</h1></header>
  <h2>Colorize Siblings</h2>
  <p>When one of the &quot;li&quot;&apos;s is clicked:</p>
  <ol>
    <li>Update the background color of all li&apos;s to the color value of the clicked &quot;li&quot;</li>
    <li>Make only the clicked item bold and uppercase</li>
  </ol>
  <ul id="colors" class="color-list">
    <li>red</li>
    <li>orange</li>
    <li>yellow</li>
    <li>green</li>
    <li>blue</li>
    <li>indigo</li>
    <li>violet</li>
  </ul>
  <script>

  // code
  </script>

  <hr>

  <h2>Tab Switching</h2>
  <p>Add the jQuery so that when a nav item is clicked:</p>
  <ol>
    <li>It becomes the active nav item (the light gray color)</li>
    <li>The content below switches to show the correct section</li>
  </ol>
  <p><b>NOTE:</b> the page should not try and anchor link down to the target section.</p>

  <div class="tabs">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#one">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="tabs-sections">
      <section id="one" class="s s1">
        <h2>Section One</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <b>consectetur adipisicing elit</b>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, <i>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</i> laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </section>
      <section id="two" class="s s2">
        <h2>Section Two</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <b>consectetur adipisicing elit</b>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, <i>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</i> laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </section>
      <section id="three" class="s s3">
        <h2>Section Three</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <b>consectetur adipisicing elit</b>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, <i>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</i> laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
  // code
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried. Hint: `$(this).text()` will be the content of the clicked item.

Comment: This looks like homework. I suggest that you do some research and make an attempt. If you get stuck, let us know what you tried and what specifically goes wrong.

Comment: @Barmar , I will give it a go and show you what I have. In a beginner web class with no prior experience, so almost have no clue how to even begin. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that what they teach in the class?

Comment: Yes and no. Prof basically teaches the basics and then we sort of have to figure out the rest ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.color-list').on("click",  function (e) {
    $('.color-list').children().css("background-color", $(e.target).text());
    $('.color-list').children().css("font-weight", "");
    $(e.target).css("font-weight", "bold");
    $('.color-list').children().css("text-transform", "");
    $(e.target).css("text-transform", "uppercase");
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thank you this works really well, appreciate it!!